# Openvpn Compromise scenario

Tags: openvpn, security

Scenario :

2 Certification Authorities used for Openvpn - one CA for client certs and another CA for server certs.

Question :

Say the CA handing out client certificates is compromised - assuming a mitm captures the traffic can the clients information be decrypted considering the CA giving out server certs (along with the server crt/key) is still confidential?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - they would need the server key.

Comment: So the user cert/key provides authentication only and the server key/cert provides confidentiality?